# I cannot add a new Trigger to Google Script. UI Change

Tags: google-apps-script

this may be a stupid question but I used to be able to add Triggers in the Google UI but just recently, I am not able to do this anymore. Here is a screenshot. Can somebody help?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You need to add the trigger from the relevant project. Not from the My Triggers page.

Comment: @Tini So, Tini, did this resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you.